# Explaining how in a poset, $P$, it contains a chain of length $l$, yet has a maximal chain of length less than $l$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Give an example of a poset $P$ such that if $l$ is the length of the longest chain of $P$, then every $t \in P$ is contained in a chain of length $l$, yet $P$ has a maximal chain of length less than $l$

The following is an example of a poset, the points are labeled arbitrarily and not actually part of the poset

```
          6
          |
          |
   3      5
  / \    /
 /   \  /
2     4
|
|             
1
```

Here the longest chain is of length 3, but the maximal chain is of length 2.
From what I understand, the two longest chains would be {1,2,3}, or {4, 5, 6}.

I think I may be confusing maximum, with maximal chain.  Can someone point out the maximal chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is fine.

A chain is *maximal* if it is not a subset of a longer chain. Your example has three maximal chains, $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{3,4\}$, and $\{4,5,6\}$. The length of the longest chain(s) is $3$, and every element of the set is contained in a chain of length $3$, but $\{3,4\}$ is a maximal chain of length less than $3$.

Comment: Oh. This makes more sense. I was thinking of chains only going up, but I now see that {3, 4} is also a chain. Thanks.

Comment: @SharpObject: You’re welcome. (Remember, as you said, the labels that you attached to the elements are arbitrary, so the fact that $3$ is ‘larger’ than $4$ in the partial order isn’t a problem.)